# Is there any word in other languages that begins with the urdu alphabet ṛē (ڑ‎)?

Tags: phonology, ipa, urdu

So in Urdu language there is no word starting with **Ṛe "ڑ"** IPA /ɽ/ but I think there may be some words in another language that begins with  Ṛe "ڑ" or have similar sound.

Comment: There are probably languages where a retroflex r can be word-initial, but the use of the Urdu alphabet is a quite specific demand, and accidental at the same time, because the language does not depend on its written form. Even Hindustani (the union of Hindi and Urdu) can be written in several scripts.

Comment: Fun result: Searching for the letter alone yields a Muslim Baby name site showing a name starting with that letter: 
Islamic Muslim Baby Girl Names starting with " ڑ " Ray
NAME  MEANING  URDU
Rudmira  Brownish, Diminutive Of Samra  ڑمیرا

Comment: Retroflexes are very common in Australian languages, and the retroflex r is perhaps the most common of these segments. [Here's a paper](https://www.academia.edu/7033502/The_diachronic_origins_of_retroflex_phonotactics) that discusses retroflex phonotactics and some languages that allow them in different locations (including as initial)

Answer (score 5):

In [Pashto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashto) (Indo-Iranian), the word for ‘blind’ does begin with /ɽ/ and is also written with **‘ڑ’** in some scripts, though most widely accepted scripts use **ړ**.

- blind: [ɽʉ̃n] (it's also pronounced with [ɻ])

Comment: There may be other words, but I can't come up with any atm.

Answer (score 3):

Augmenting [@JoyfulSadness's answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/38767), assuming `ړ` as the corresponding Pashto phoneme for Urdu's `ڑ`, here are couple of Pashto words: [ړومبی](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%DA%93%D9%88%D9%85%D8%A8%DB%8C#Pashto) (dialectal form of [لومړی](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D9%84%D9%88%D9%85%DA%93%DB%8C#Pashto)), and [ړوند](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%DA%93%D9%88%D9%86%D8%AF).

In Sindhi & Shina Abjad, it is written as `ڙ`. Example: [ڙک](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%DA%99%DA%A9)

Shahmukhi also has `ڑ` same as in Urdu, similarly but do not have words starting with that phoneme.

---

In general, most Indo-Iranian languages do not have words that begin with /ɽ/. Just like Urdu, the corresponding phoneme in Hindi (Devanagari `ड़`) is not used to start any word.